# How to handle video and image upload to storage servers?

Tags: php, go, data-storage, zfs

I am in the process of developing an application (in Go or possibly in PHP) where users needs to upload photos and images.

I have setup up a couple of ZFS (mirror) storage servers on different locations, but I am in doubt about how to let users best upload files. ZFS handles quotas and reservation.

I am running with a replicated Galera database on all servers, both for safety, but also for easy access to user accounts from each server. In other words, each server has a local copy of the database all the time. All users are virtual users **only**.

So far I have testes the following setup options:

**Solution 1**

Running SFTP (ProFTPD with module) or FTPS (Pure-FTPs with TLS) on the storage servers with virtual users.

This gives people direct access to the storage servers using a client like Filezilla. At the same time users can also upload using our web GUI from our main web server.

One advantage with this setup is that the FTP server can handle virtual users. Our web application will also send files via SFTP or FTPS.

One disadvantage is that FTP is meeh, annoying to firewall. Also I much prefer FTP over SSH (SFTP), rather than FTP over TLS (FTPS). However, only ProFTPD has a module for SSH, but it has been a real pain (many problems with non-working configuration options and file permission errors) to work with compared to PureFTPd, but PureFTPd only supports TLS.

Running with real SSH/SCP accounts and using PAM is **not** an option.

**Solution 2**

Mount the storage servers locally on the web server using NFS or CIFS (Samba is great at automatic resume in case a box goes down).

In this setup users can **only** upload via our main web server. The web server application, and the application running on the storage servers, then needs to support resumable uploads. I have been looking into using the tus protocol.

A disadvantage with both the above setups is that storage capacity needs to be managed somehow. When storage server 1 reaches its maximum number of users, the application needs to know this and then only create virtual users for storage server 2, 3, etc.

I have calculated how many users each storage server can hold and then have the web application check the database with virtual users to see when it needs to move newly created users to the next storage server.

This is rather old school, but it works.

**Solution 3**

Same as solution 2 (no FTP), but clone our web application upload thingy to each storage server and then redirect users (or provide them with a physical link to the storage server, s1.example.com, s2.example.com, etc.)

The possibly advantage with this setup is that users upload directly to the storage server they have been assigned to rather than go trough our main web server (preventing it from becoming a possible bottleneck).

**Solution 4**

Use GlusterFS on the storage servers and build a cluster that can easily be expanded. I have tested out GlusterFS and it works very well for this purpose.

The advantage with this setup is that I don't really need to care about where files physically go on which storage servers, and I can easily expand storage by adding more servers to the cluster.

However, the disadvantage here is again that our main web server might become a bottleneck.

I have also considered adding a load balancer and then use multiple web server in case our main web server becomes a bottleneck for uploading files.

In any case, I much prefer to keep it simple! I don't like adding stuff. I want it to be easy to maintain in the long run.

Any ideas, suggestions, and advice will be greatly appreciated.

How do you do it?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

A web application should be agnostic of the underlying storage in case we are talking of file storage; Separation of concerns.

(S)FTP(S) on the other hand is not a storage method. It is a communication protocol. It does not preclude you from having a shared storage. See above.

ZFS does not come with the ability of shared storage included, so you are basically down to the following choices:

1. Which underlying filesystem?
2. Do I want to offer an additional access mode via (S)FTP(S)?
3. How do I make my filesystem available across multiple servers? GlusterFS, CIFS or NFS?

So, let us walk this through.

## Filesystem

I know ZFS is intriguing, but here is the thing: xfs for example already has a maximum filesystem size of 8 exbibytes minus one byte. The specialist term for this is "a s...load". To give you a relation: The library of congress holds about 20TB of digital media - and would fit into that roughly 400k times. Even good ol' ext4 can hold 50k LoCs. And if you hold that much data, your FS is your smallest concern. Building the next couple of power plants to keep your stuff going presumably is.

**Gist** Nice to think about, but use whatever you feel comfortable with. I personally use xfs (on LVM) for pretty much everything.

## Additional access methods

Sure, why not? Aside from the security nightmare (privilege escalation, anyone?). And ProFTPd, with it's in build coffee machine and kitchen sink is the *last* FTP server I would use for anything. It has a ginormous code base, which lends itself to [accidentally introducing vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/16873/Proftpd-Proftpd.html?vendor_id=9520).

Basically it boils down to the skills present in the project. Can you guys ***properly*** harden a system and an FTP server and ***monitor*** it for security incidents? Unless your answer is a confident "Yes, ofc, plenty with experience with it!" you should minimize the attack surface you present.

**Gist** Don't, unless you really know what you are doing. And if you have to ask, you probably do not. No offense intended, just stating facts.

## Shared filesystem

Personally, I have made... less than perfect experiences with GlusterFS. The replication has quite some requirements when it comes to network latency and stuff. In a nutshell: if we are talking of multiple availability zones, say EMEA, APAC and NCSA, it is close to impossible. You'd be stuck to [georeplication](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Geo%20Replication/), which is less than ideal for the use case you describe.

NFS and CIFS on the other hand have the problem that there is no replication at all, and all clients need to access the same server instance in order to access the data - hardly a good idea if you think you need an underlying ZFS to get along.

**Gist** Shared filesystems at a global scale with halfway decent replication lags and access times are ***very*** hard to do and can get ***very*** expensive.

## Haha, Smartypants, so what would you suggest?

Scale. Slowly. In the beginning, you should be able to get along with a simple FS based repository for your files. And then check various other means for large scale shared storage and migrate to it.

Taking the turn towards implementation, I would even go a step further, you should make your storage an interface:

```golang
// Storer takes the source and stores its contents under path for further reading via
// Retriever.
type Storer interface {
    StreamTo(path string, source io.Reader) (err error)
}

// Retriever takes a path and streams the file it has stored under path to w.
type Retriever interface {
    StreamFrom(path string, w io.Writer) (err error)
}

// Repository is a composite interface. It requires a
// repository to accept andf provide streams of files
type Repository interface {
    Storer
    Retriever
    Close() error
}
```

Now, you can implement various storage methods quite easily:

```golang
// FileStore represents a filesystem based file Repository.
type FileStore struct {
    basepath string
}

// StreamFrom statisfies the Retriever interface.
func (s *FileStore) StreamFrom(path string, w io.Writer) (err error) {

    f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath.Join(s.basepath, path), os.O_RDONLY|os.O_EXCL, 0640)
    if err != nil {
        return handleErr(path, err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(w, f)
    return err
}
```

Personally, I think this would be a great use case for [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), which, despite its name is not a filesystem, but a feature of MongoDB. As for the reasons:

1. MongoDB comes with a concept called replica sets to ensure availability with transparent automatic failover between servers
2. It comes with a rather simple mechanism of automatic data partitioning, called a sharded cluster
3. It comes with an indefinite number of access gateways called `mongos` query routers to access your sharded data.
4. For the client, aside from the connection URL, all this is transparent. So it does not make a difference (almost, aside from [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) and [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/)) whether it's storage backend consists of a single server or a globally replicated sharded cluster with 600 nodes.
5. If done properly, there is not a single point of failure, you can replicate across availability zones while keeping the "hot" data close to the respective users.

I have created a [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/gridfileserv) which contains an example of the interface suggestion and implements a filesystem based repository as well as a MongoDB repository. You might want to have a look at it. It lacks caching at the moment. In case you would like to see that implemented, please open an issue there.

Comment: Agree overall (except boo non-ZFS ;) — it’s not just good for the storage capacity). GridFS seems like a reasonable option if you want to store the data on-prem. But if you’re building in a cloud environment already then you should just use whatever blob storage your cloud provider offers (Google Cloud Storage, Amazon S3, etc.) because then you don’t have to care about the underlying storage implementation and can focus more on the user-facing parts of your product.

Comment: Agreed. And depending on what you want to do, and especially if you want to be prepared for easy migration, even Minio would be a good choice. It is hard to say without  knowing the exact requirements.